# PHP - Changing an Object for Consistency

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I have a scenario where an API is returning multiple records inside object containing a numeric array like so;

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Event] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 111
                    [Name] => My First Event
                    [EventType] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 1
                            [Category] => Music
                        )
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 222
                    [Name] => My Second Event
                    [EventType] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 2
                            [Category] => Sport
                        )
                )
        )

    [Errors] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Result] => 0
            [Message] => 
        )

    [RecordCount] => 2
)
```

I'm current using a foreach loop to iterate through the records. This works fine.

```
foreach($result->Event as $Event)
```

But there is a problem here I have a scenario where a single results is returned in the object like so;

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Event] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 11
            [Name] => My Only Event
            [EventType] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 2
                    [Category] => Sport
                )

        )

    [Errors] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Result] => 0
            [Message] => 
        )

    [RecordCount] => 1
)
```

Notice there is no [0] array index for the single results.

What's the best way to overcome this keeping in mind that I have no control of the data returned by the API?

Comment: I presume that [is_array()](http://php.net/is_array).

Comment: If I need do two separate pieces of logic dependant on whether there is an array or not it could get quite messy.

Comment: Then complaint to the API owners (I don't like that design either).

Comment: I think the best way is to modify the API

Comment: Yes In an ideal world perhaps. Would it not be possible to add the array to the single result as a workaround?

Comment: don't see how it could be messy to add a conditional, you have `RecordCount`, you can rely on that to retrieve either one `Event` or many... something like `if($result->RecordCount == 1) ? return $result->Event : return theForEachHere;`

Comment: The object is simplified for the purpose of this question. I need to do a lot of conditional checking against the data returned in the object. If I'm going this checking once in a foreach loop and once again for a single result it seems unnecessarily repetitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best workaround I have found is to add the single Event to an array with a zero index within the result object. This way the result object matches the same structure as a result containing multiple records.

```
if(!is_array($result->Event)){
    $result->Event = array($result->Event);
}
```

Comment: I edited this to check if Event is not an array instead. This would then be ignored if the API owner changes their approach to returning single records as arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `Event` is an array or an object

```
if( is_object( $result->Event ) )
{
  // ...
}
else
{
  foreach( // [....]
}
```

You may process the object or overwrite it with a 1 item array as suggested by [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1582152/sam)

---

*Btw: very bad API design. I would complain....*